# How to ungroup units in Battle for Middle Earth lotr pc game?

Tags: pc, battle-for-middle-earth

I selected archers and moved them behind peasants. Instead they have joined forces. Now whenever I select archers peasants also get selected. The archers shoot arrows while peasants idly stand and watch. How to ungroup them again?

This is Lotr: Battle for Middle Earth (but I think it should be the same for BFME2 also).

(Also any tips to turn this grouping feature off or to avoid this kind of problem in the future would be appreciated). Please reply fast this is urgent. Thanks.

Comment: Battle for Middle Earth 2 does not have the same feature - instead of grouping, large groups of soldiers can be set in formations, automatically staggered for protection. There is no permanent grouping.

Comment: yeah i use tower guards and archers or elven warriors with bows and elven warriors with swords(for the good teams). the only way to split em is to kill em but that kills the whole lot not seperate them but i can just train them again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game manual explicitly says:
"Some Battalions may be combined together. Left-click a Battalion and move the mouse over another Battalion. If an arrow appears, right-click to combine the Battalions. Combined Battalions cannot be separated again."

The only combination of battalions I remember is a row of archers with a row of melee units. Be careful what you click on with those units selected.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for your answer. Anyways, meanwhile I have discovered the true use of combining archers and peasants. When an enemy unit draws closer thats when they too attack. They kinda serve as protection for archers I guess.